# Mapping matrix to dictionary (key:column)

Tags: python, dictionary, matrix, mapping

I'm struggling with this function here hoping you could assist.

Given a non-empty matrix I need to map it to a dictionary of lists, as the key for each item is the J-th column
i.e.
Matrix:

```
[[1,2,3][4,5,6],[7,8,9,10]]
```

dictionary:

```
{0:[1,4,7],1:[2,5,8],2:[3,6,9],3:[10]}
```

definition:

```
matrixToDict(mat)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Answer (score 0):

```
def matrixToDict(mat):
   list2 = []
   maxLength = max(len(x) for x in mat)
   for j in range(maxLength):
       list1 = []
       for i in range(len(mat)):
           if (len(mat[i])-1) >= j:
               list1.append(mat[i][j])
       list2.append(list1)   
   dic = { i : list2[i] for i in range(0, len(list2) ) }
   return dic

mat = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9,10]]
matrixToDict(mat)
```

Output:
{0: [1, 4, 7], 1: [2, 5, 8], 2: [3, 6, 9], 3: [10]}